# help with custom order grid

Tags: custom, order-grid

I am trying to make a grid with all the orders containing the same product grouped together (all the orders only have one product in them) any ideas how to achieve this? this is what i have so far the last line is breaking my code if i group by city or company it works how do i get group by products to work?

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->join(array('a' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = a.parent_id AND a.address_type != \'billing\'', array(
            'company'    => 'company',
            'city'       => 'city',
            'country_id' => 'country_id'
        ))
        ->join(array('c' => 'customer/customer_group'), 'main_table.customer_group_id = c.customer_group_id', array(
            'customer_group_code' => 'customer_group_code'
        ))
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'fullname',
            'CONCAT({{customer_firstname}}, \' \', {{customer_lastname}})',
            array('customer_firstname' => 'main_table.customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname' => 'main_table.customer_lastname'))
        ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
            'products',
            '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name)
                FROM sales_flat_order_item x
                WHERE {{entity_id}} = x.order_id
                    AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')',
            array('entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id')
        );
        $collection->getSelect()->group('products');
```

Answer (score 1):

ok i got it

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('status')->group('company')
->group('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name) FROM sales_flat_order_item x WHERE main_table.entity_id = x.order_id AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')')
->columns(array('total_qty' => 'count(`main_table`.`grand_total`)','grand_total_sum' => 'sum(`main_table`.`grand_total`)'));
```